# Add a dynamic email in between localized translations

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have implemented internationalized with a custom redux store instead of going with i18next package and it is working fine. However I wanted to know how can I add a dynamic property value in between a translated line? For e.g If i have a sentence like this that needs to be translated in multiple languages

```
<span>
  An email has been sent to {email}. Please follow the instructions received to enter your account
<span>
```

How can I create the json translation for this line then such that the translaton should only be in one proeprty and it should fetch the email property when getting rendered into the component.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [i18next interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation),

```json
{
  "key": "An email has been sent to {{email}}. Please follow the instructions received to enter your account"
}
```

```js
i18next.t('key', { email: 'my@email.com' });
```

It is not i18next responsibility to fetch the email value.

Comment: please check this thread too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024480/nextjs-api-route-custom-cron-job